# Vitest alias or inline.deps fail to resolve import error

Tags: vite, vitest

I am migrating some jest tests over to vitest and some of my tests are failing due to an import issue of an external package dependency in `node_modules`. Specifically: `@package/dependency seems to be an ES Module but shipped in a CommonJS package`.

vitest suggests this change to my config:

```js
export default {
  test: {
    deps: {
      inline: [
        "@package"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, this fix does not work. Previously I resolved this issue with `moduleNameMapper` in jest where `"@package/dependency": "@package/dependency/js"` mapped to a valid import. I tried setting `alias` in both `test.alias` and `resolve.alias`, but neither works.

I am using Typescript in this project, and the rest of my test config looks like this:

```js
test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
    setupFiles: "./src/setupTests.js",
}
```

```js
// setupTests.js
import {configure} from 'enzyme/build';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16/build';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

What can I do to get around this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

possible solution is:

```
test: { deps: { optimizer: { include: ["@package"] } } }
```

but this should to work only for external library like `react-leaflet-cluster` but again this will fail to load css files